# Bootstrap - horizontal Aligning Text Fields

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align textfields with bootstrap however I keep failing to adopt anything I found on sources to my project. What I am trying to do is aligning e-mail and password text-fields but leave *'Remember me'* and *'Login'* centered.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

     <form method="POST" action="/auth/login">

       <div class="form-group">    
         <div>
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">  
         <div>
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
         </div>
       </div>

      <div class="form-group">  
        <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
           </label>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="form-group">  
       <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
       </div>
     </div>

 </form>
```

Comment: You can target the text inputs by using a css attribute selector.

For example...

    input[type="text"] {
        ....
    }

Comment: add text-center class along form-group to center the inner content of the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's `form-horizontal` class to help achieve the layout.

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/nJ2P2gi76B

```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could post a JSFiddle with the css you are using!

Guessing from what i see:

- You could add a class to both fields and override the css.
- or put both fields in a div and align them without impacting the rest.

Using an enclosing div:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7m0xqgx/)

CSS:

```
.input-fields {
    width: 300px;
}

.input-fields .form-group {
    float: right;
}

.form-group {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
 <div class="input-fields">
   <div class="form-group">    
     <div>
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">  
     <div>
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">  
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
       </label>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">  
   <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
   </div>
 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I am using <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

Comment: @seg-s  it is not an answer so you should do this in comments but not as answer

Comment: Do you have a css file that you can modify? (one you made, ore do you have css in your html?)

Comment: @Muhammad you need 50rep to comment, and apart from the first sentence it is an answer!

Comment: Edited the OP. nope, I don't have a custom css, I was just tweaking the bootstrap

Comment: Added an example with modified html & css.

Answer (score 0):

You can access only the text input by using a css attribute selector.

For Example...

```
input[type="text"] {
   ...
}
```

You can get more specific if needed...

```
#someID input[type="text"] {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `text-center` to center the inner content of your div. you can use `text-left`, `text-center`, `text-right` classes to align the contents.

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css);
```

```html
 <form method="POST" action="/auth/login">

  <div class="form-group">    
   <div>
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">  
   <div>
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-center">  
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-center">  
   <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
   </div>
  </div>

 </form>
```